# How to make QHeaderView width synchronizing with parent

Tags: qt, resize, subclassing, qheaderview

I subclassed QHeaderView for QTreeWidget and called setHeader with its object. Now the header has fixed width instead of width equaling to the parent width. How can I synchronize them?

[image]

Comment: Create a sample of this behavior. Probably you'll find a mistake while preparing it. What you've described works correctly.

Comment: how do you mean like the text isnt fully shown because the header has a small fixed width or the header bar isnt stretching across the entire treewidget header area?